# MS Access: VBA Code runs slow

Tags: vba, ms-access

Need your help guys on how can I can make below code run faster. It take me 3 hrs to run this code.

To give you idea on my table, I have 3 fields (Account Number,Amount,Concatenate Account Number/Amount) I really have no primary key and I'm relying on the fields specifically the concatenate data as basis for my matching. What I really want to get is the unmatched records for both tables and the code really help solve my problem. The only issue I got is the processing time because I have 25,000 records for both tables. Hope you guys make the processing time shorter.

```
Dim rstT1 As Recordset
Dim rstUpdate As Recordset
Dim iMatching As String
Dim iT1, iT2 As Long
Dim iMatchNum As Long
Dim iMatchID As Long
Dim i As Long




CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE Table01 SET MatchNum = null")
CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE Table02 SET MatchNum = null")
Set rstT1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryTable1Processing1")




Do While rstT1.EOF <> True
iMatching = rstT1!User_ID
iT1 = DCount("*", "Table01", "[User_ID] = '" & iMatching & "'")
iT2 = DCount("*", "Table02", "[Combine] = '" & iMatching & "'")
If iT1 > 0 And iT2 > 0 Then
If iT1 > iT2 Then
iMatchNum = iT2
Else
iMatchNum = iT1
End If

Debug.Print dDate & " " & iMatchNum
Set rstUpdate = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP " & iMatchNum & " MatchNum FROM Table01 WHERE [User_ID] = '" & iMatching & "'")
i = 0
Do While rstUpdate.EOF <> True
i = i + 1
rstUpdate.Edit
rstUpdate!matchnum = iMatchID + i
rstUpdate.Update
rstUpdate.MoveNext
Loop
rstUpdate.Close
Set rstUpdate = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP " & iMatchNum & " MatchNum FROM Table02 WHERE [Combine] = '" & iMatching & "'")
i = 0
Do While rstUpdate.EOF <> True
i = i + 1
rstUpdate.Edit
rstUpdate!matchnum = iMatchID + i
rstUpdate.Update
rstUpdate.MoveNext
Loop
rstUpdate.Close

Debug.Print "adding " & iMatchID & " to " & iMatchNum
iMatchID = iMatchID + iMatchNum
End If
rstT1.MoveNext
Loop
rstT1.Close
Set rstT1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing to check is if you have set an index on `[User_ID]` and on `[Combine]`.

Comment: sir @Gustav i don't create index for the two fields.

Comment: Well, then do so. It can't hurt.

Comment: sir @Gustav the two fields have duplicate value hence, I can't set an index.

Comment: Yes you can, just not as a unique index.

Comment: thanks for the advice sir @Gustav I'll do it.

Comment: Aside from indexing and adding PK's, which has already been mentioned, you need to rethink the whole process. Using DCount and walking through each record one by one will be slow, no matter what you do. I would use queries to determine the records to be updated, dump the results into a temp table, if needed, then create an update query joining the temp table to the table to be updated and run it. For 25,000 records, my guess would be less than a minute, certainly not hours.

Comment: Solve- thanks @Gustav it works. It only runs less than a minute..

Comment: thanks @AVG for the inputs.